# Setting the contents of a tab in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-tabhost

Using TabHost and TabWidget i've created two tabs in android, the problem with the second tab is that it has to display a list view with images. 
So I've used the idea given here http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android/

So my tab2 refers to mail.xml given in that link. How do i call the mainactivity.java from tab2 so that the contents of the list gets displayed?

```
.//tab 1 contents
.
TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Categories");
spec2.setIndicator("Categories",
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_categories));
spec2.setContent(R.id.main);
.
.
```

Here i need to call the class which creates that list view using a simple adapter. How do i do that?
Kindly reply

Comment: FYI tab2 contents are inside an xml. So i've named that tag2 id to be main. so R.id.main is valid..

Answer (score 1):

By inflating layout

For inflating

Dont know which layout you are using

```
LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflate.inflate(R.id.main, null);
```

now you can set this in tab as contentView

```
spec2.setContent(view);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you need to open MainActivity in Tab2.
For that you will have to do the following:

```
TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Categories");
spec2.setIndicator("Categories",
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_categories));
Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext( ), MainActivity.class );
spec2.setContent( intent );
```